# "cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement" How do I return cursor results from a PostgreSQL Function in KOA service

Tags: node.js, postgresql, plpgsql, koa

I am using PostgreSQL FUNCTION to return result sets. I am having trouble getting my Node.js/KOA api to call it properly with parameters. I can get it to work without parameters, but the parameters turn it into a prepared statement. And the prepared statements don't like multiple commands.

Here is the database object and configuration that I use:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const config = require('../configuration');

exports.pool = this.pool;

exports.start = async function() {
    const host = config.get("PGHOST");
    const user = config.get("PGUSER");
    const port = config.get("PGPORT");
    const password = config.get("PGPASSWORD");
    const database = config.get("PGDATABASE");

    this.pool = new Pool({ user, host, database, password, port });

    console.log('Postgres database pool started.');
};

exports.close = async function() {
    await this.pool.end;
};

exports.query = async function(query, data) {
    let rs = await this.pool.query(query, data);
    return rs;
};
```

Here is my KOA service (it uses the pg.Pool node module, and where my issue is, i think...):

```
let getFilteredDevelopers = async (developerId, firstName, lastName) => {
    let query = { 
        text: `
            BEGIN;
            SELECT ks_get_filtered_developers($1, $2, $3);
            FETCH ALL IN "ks_developers_cursor";
            COMMIT;
        `,
        values: [ developerId, firstName, lastName  ] 
    };

    try {
        let result = await database.query(query);
        return result[2].rows;
    } catch (error) {
        return `Failed to fetch developers.`;
    }
};
```

This approach works fine without the parameters. But when I add the parameters to the koa pg call, it throws the error: 'cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement'.

The following is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ks_get_filtered_developers (
    p_developer_id NUMERIC,
    p_first_name TEXT,
    p_last_name TEXT
) RETURNS refcursor AS
$$
    DECLARE
      v_query TEXT = '';
      v_where_clause TEXT = '';
      v_developers_cursor refcursor = 'ks_developers_cursor';
    BEGIN

        IF (p_developer_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
            v_where_clause = v_where_clause || FORMAT(' AND d.developer_id = %s ', p_developer_id);
        END IF;

        v_query = '
            SELECT d.developer_id AS id, d.* 
            FROM ks_developers d
            WHERE 1=1
        ' || v_where_clause || '
            ORDER BY d.developer_id
        ';

        OPEN v_developers_cursor FOR 
            EXECUTE v_query;

        RETURN v_developers_cursor;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I implement this in the appropriate way? What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my lack of understanding on how to use the pg node module. Basically, I was trying to jam everything into one query, because I thought I had to. I forgot that I created a "helper" query in the database module, and that it was narrow. I got that confused with the pg pool query function name. I was shooting myself in the foot.

This is the article that showed me how multiple statements should be done with a transaction:

https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions

So for a quick fix on this question, I exposed the pool to myself and started querying the pool, and then released the connection. This allows for multiple prepared statements and actions.

Here is what I modified my koa to be:

```
let getFilteredDevelopers = async (developerId, firstName, lastName) => {
    const client = await database.pool.connect();
    try {
        await client.query('BEGIN');
        const selectQuery = `SELECT ks_get_filtered_developers($1, $2, $3)`;
        await client.query(selectQuery, [ developerId, firstName, lastName ]);
        const fetchQuery = `FETCH ALL IN "ks_developers_cursor"`;
        const result = await client.query(fetchQuery);
        client.query('COMMIT');
        return result.rows;
    } catch (error) {
        client.query('ROLLBACK');
        return `Failed to fetch developers.`;
    } finally {
        client.release();
    }
};
```

I will be refactoring my code to handle this better, but I wanted to answer the question of why this code doesn't work, and what I was misunderstanding.